# c# /xamarin forms get randoms items form sqlite datababe

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am using sqlite-net-pcl [click here to see](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

My question is : I am looking for a way to get random items from my sqlite database , I have found the query but I cannot see how to do it with sqlite database

The Query is as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT x)
```

sorry for my question.
Thanks in advance , if there is a better solution I will take

Comment: Use 'select top x' instead of limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `Query` method

```
return db.Query<TypeName> ("select * from TableName");
```